# System.Drawing.Image.FromStream invalid parameter

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to get the blob from the database but sometimes I'm getting error "invalid parameter"

in this line

```
System.Drawing.Image objimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(blobstream, true);
```

Here is  my code:

```
public partial class showblob : System.Web.UI.Page
{

     private System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort delegateabort;
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         // Get a handle on account, create a blob service client and get container proxy
         var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("Conn"));
         account.CreateCloudTableClient().CreateTableIfNotExist("tablename");
         var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
         CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference("tablename");
         string id = Request["id"].ToString();

         // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob"
         CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference(id);
         BlobStream blobstream = blob.OpenRead();

         if (Request["imgvd"] == "0")
         {
             Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
             System.Drawing.Image objimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(blobstream, true);

             if (Request["thumb"] != null)
                 objimg = objimg.GetThumbnailImage(140, 210, delegateabort, System.IntPtr.Zero);

             objimg.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
         }
```

And have image stored because I have already add using this method:

```
if (fileFoto.HasFile)

     try
     {
         CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
         // Retrieve a reference to a container 
         CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("tablename");
         // Create the container if it doesn't already exist
         container.CreateIfNotExist();
         CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference("c" + ViewState["id"].ToString());               
         blob.UploadFromStream(fileFoto.PostedFile.InputStream);
     }
```

Comment: is it an exception?  what does the actual stack trace look like?

Comment: yes, is an exception... in `                System.Drawing.Image objimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(blobstream, true);`

Comment: I thing that the method which I used for add photo doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. The problem was that I set the reference as

```
CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference("c" + ViewState["id"].ToString());
```

When I upload the photo and take it using

```
CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference(ViewState["id"].ToString());
```